# Why does this relay only turn on after being unplugged?

Tags: relay

I am working on a system from 1986. It has an old-fashioned 12VDC relay like the one in the picture.

When the circuit powering the relay coil is turned on, the relay does not switch on. When I unplug the relay and then plug it back in, with the circuit still on, it flips on.

While testing I found that the relay coil is only getting about 11.1-11.5VDC of the 12.5 that it should have (likely caused by corroded wires.)

Could this lower voltage be the issue? If so, why does taking it out and putting back in cause it to switch on?

[image]

Comment: A data sheet of the relay is required.

Comment: Perhaps the force of plugging it back in temporarily improves conduction through those corroded connectors?

Comment: Bad contacts in socket.

Comment: how is the voltage turned on? if it comes up slowly it could be the reason.

Comment: Is it a latching relay with bipolar drive?  Normally 2/3 of rated is sufficient, more is faster. Never assume we know , what, where , how , in a question and include all details or link to specs, also is it repeatable and record all voltage states.

Comment: @Hoagie I am still learning the nomenclature so excuse me because I don't know what you mean by "latching relay with bipolar drive". I do know that it is on a car so it is run off 12VDC battery, and there is a separate ground for both the coil and switch. The relay behaves exactly the same every time. 12.6VDC at the battery, 11.1VDC between relay coil + terminal and battery - terminal. The never comes on when the circuit is initially powered up. It always turns on (and stays on) after being unplugged and plugged back in with the circuit still powered.

Comment: @danmcb The voltage is turned on by a transistor on a circuit board, which is activated by a manual switch. So the power comes on all at once.

Comment: You need to define car, relay function, part number and all the symptoms over time in question. This is essential to all question contents. Links help too.

Comment: 1. Remove relay and test it with a load and meter or a bulb with a battery. 2. Replace if bad, 3. Analyze system if good

Comment: @Hoagie I have replaced the relay with a known good relay and it has the same symptoms. I used the first relay in another circuit and it behaves normally. I know how to do basic troubleshooting. If you needed me to tell you what kind of car it is then I’m confident that you will not be able to provide me with useful info as all cars run on the same 12.6VDC system. I was hope for some kind of explanation from someone who is versed in electromagnetic physics who could provide some kind of explanation for the strange behavior

Comment: The car system can turn a momentary switch into a latching function. It seems some other failure is the cause. This feature may have end-stop or thermal cutoffs or other feedback mechanisms unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a datasheet, and confirm it is a simple SPNO relay, but assuming it is, I would guess either rust on the pivots or contact damage.

When the circuit is initially on, and the relay still open, have you tried giving the relay can a few sharp taps with something metal (a.k.a. "percussive maintenance")?  You might well find it flips.

You could also use a screwdriver to unbend the crimps which hold on the lid, and see what is actually happening inside.  I had a similar problem with a glowplug relay on an outside diesel generator, and it turned out moisture over the years had cause enough rust to make the hinge temperamental.

Comment: I am not very well-versed in the nomenclature, but it is a normally open relay. I will try the percussive maintenance and see if it flips. If I can find another relay I will try it and see if it is a problem with the relay or the power supply.

Comment: Did you ever try this, and how did it go? It would help others if you tell us what the solution was.  If it was rust, mark this question as answered.